# Populating namespace within a module before loading it

Tags: python, namespaces, import

I designed a configuration mechanism in Python, where certain objects can operate in special ways to define problems in our domain.

The user specifies the problem by using this objects in a "config-file" manner. For instance:

```
# run configuration
CASES = [
 ('Case 1', Item('item1') + Item('item2') + Item('item3')),
 ('Case 2', Item('item1') + Item('item4')),
]

DATA = {
 'Case 1' = {'Piece 1': 'path 1'},
 'Case 2' = {'Piece 1': 'path 2'},
}
```

The `Item` objects are, of course, defined in a specific module. In order to use them you have to issue an `import` statement: `from models import Item` (of course, my actual imports are more complex, not a single one).

I would like the user to simply write the configuration presented, without having to import  anything (users very easily can forget this).

I thought of reading the file as text, and creating a secondary text file with all the appropriate imports at the top, write that to a file, and import that file, but this seems clumsy.

Any advice?

Edit:

The workflow of my system is somewhat similar to Django, in that the user defines the "Settings" in a python file, and runs a script which imports that Settings file and does things with it. That is where I would like this functionality, to tell Python "given this namespace (where `Item` means something in particular), the user will provide a script - execute it and hand me the result so that I can spawn the different runs".

Answer (score 1):

From the `eval` help:

```
>>> help(eval)
Help on built-in function eval in module __builtin__:

eval(...)
    eval(source[, globals[, locals]]) -> value

    Evaluate the source in the context of globals and locals.
    The source may be a string representing a Python expression
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

That is, you can pass in an arbitrary dictionary to use as the namespace for an `eval` call.

```
with open(source) as f:
    eval(f.read, globals(), {'Item': Item})
```

---

Why have you decided that the user needs to write their configuration file in pure Python? There are many simple human-writable languages you could use instead. Have a look at [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html), for instance, which reads basic configuration files of the sort Windows uses.

```
[cases]
case 1: item1 + item2 + item3
case 2: item1 + item4

[data]
case 1: piece1 - path1
case 2: piece1 - path2
```

Answer (score 0):

1) the first thing that i have in mind is to offer to the user the generation of your config file; how so ?

you can add an argument in the script that launch your application :

```
$ python application_run.py --generate_settings
```

this will generate a config file with a skeleton of different import that the user should not have to add every time, something like this:

```
import sys
from models import Item

# Complete the information here please !!!
CASES = []
DATA = {}
```

2) a second way is to use [execfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) , you can for this create a script that will read the settings.py:

root_settings.py

```
# All import defined Here.
from Model import Item
...

execfile('settings.py')
```

And now to read the settings file info just import the `root_settings`, by the way all variable that have been defined in `settings.py` are now in `root_settings.py` namespace .